# Erro com Android Style

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Não estou conseguindo compilar meu projeto, recebo o seguinte erro

```
<type> attribute is required for <item>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está meu **style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- O Erro está nessa linha abaixo-->
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

</style>
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/tbbt</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

O erro está na linha 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html), um elemento `<item>` deve obrigatoriamente ser filho de um elemento `<style>`. Reveja o seguinte trecho do seu arquivo:

```
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>
```

Note que ele não possui um pai `<style>`.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Acabei não percebendo esse pequeno detalhe.